# Emit and Subscribe within Angular 9 Service don't work together

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components, angular9, angular-event-emitter

I have service called shopping list service.

```
import { Ingredient } from './ingredient.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ShoppingListService {
  constructor() { }

  ingredients = [
    new Ingredient("Protein",40),
    new Ingredient("Carbs",10),
    new Ingredient("Vitamins",10)
  ];

  ingredientEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();

  addIngredient(ingredient:Ingredient) {
    this.ingredients.push(ingredient);
  }

  addIngredientsFromRecipes(ingredients:Ingredient[]) {
    let array=[];
    for (let i=0;i<this.ingredients.length;i++) {
        array.push(this.ingredients[i]);
    }
    array.push(...ingredients);
    this.ingredientEmitter.emit(array);
    
  }
  
  provideIngredientList() {
    return this.ingredients;
  }
}
```

In the function addIngredientsFromRecipes() I „receive“ an Array of type Ingredient, which is different from the initial ingredients Array in the Service.  The array I receive looks like this. (Running the first console.log in addIngredientsFromRecipes())

```
(2) [Ingredient, Ingredient]
0: Ingredient {name: "Ingredient 3", amount: 40}
1: Ingredient {name: "Ingredient 4", amount: 70}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

In this function I also want to add the “received“ Ingredients Array to the initial ingredients Array of the service. This works because when I console.log it (second console.log in the function), it shows the initial Array with the extra Array.

```
(5) [Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient]
0: Ingredient {name: "Protein", amount: 40}
1: Ingredient {name: "Carbs", amount: 10}
2: Ingredient {name: "Vitamins", amount: 10}
3: Ingredient {name: "Ingredient 3", amount: 40}
4: Ingredient {name: "Ingredient 4", amount: 70}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The problem starts when I want to send this new Array to the Component which displays the Array via `this.ingredientEmitter.emit(this.ingredients)` in the function addIngredient(ingredient:Ingredient).

The HTML Template of the displaying component look like this:

```
<div class="container pt-5">
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">name</th>
      <th scope="col">amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
        <td> {{ingredient.name}} </td>
        <td> {{ingredient.amount}} </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The ts of the displaying component:

```
import { Component, OnInit,OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ShoppingListService } from  '../shopping-list.service';
import {Ingredient} from '../ingredient.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-ingredients',
  templateUrl: './display-ingredients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-ingredients.component.css']
})
export class DisplayIngredientsComponent implements OnInit {
  ingredients:Ingredient[];

  constructor(private shoppingListService:ShoppingListService) {
   }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ingredients = this.shoppingListService.provideIngredientList();

    this.shoppingListService.ingredientEmitter.subscribe((ingredients:any)=> {
      this.ingredients=ingredients;
    })}
    
  }
```

It seems that the subscription dosent seem to work for some reason. Can`t figure out why. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things i would try to debug: A console.log in the subscription and to remove any kind of references try to emit [...this.ingredients] in the service. Why do you use a eventEmitter in this case? I would choose a behaviourSubject so you dont need to call provideIngredientList() in the component

Comment: I dont yet knew about the behaviour subject. What do you mean by " to remove any kind of references try to emit [...this.ingredients] in the service."?

Comment: By pushing a new object into the array the reference to the array is not changing and the angular changedecection might not be running. You can remove the refernce by creating a new array with the spread syntax (3 dots).

Comment: I updated it now with a new Array but it still won't work. Can you have  a secon look at it?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I created a stackblitz for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-ingredients-test Hope it can help

Comment: Looked at it. I see what happens. When I import the timer from rxjs and use this line of code in order to test it, sublime text makes the 1000 milliseconds red and say identifier expected. Anyway thank you so much for your efforts !!!!!!!!!!!!!!